# How can correctly I get MainPage?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I first tried `MainPage rootPage = new MainPage()`, but this throws an error.

So I tried the official sample version:

**[MainPage.xaml.cs]**

```cs
namespace theMain
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static MainPage Current;

        public class MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Current = this;
        }

        public async void theFunctionIneedToAccess(P1, P2)
        {
            // Update the variable in MainPage and update the UI as well
        }
    }
}
```

**[OtherCode.cs]**

```cs
using theMain

namespace theOther
{
    public sealed partial class OtherClass
    {
        MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current; //In debugging mode, I found that I get null here

        private void SmthHappening()
        {
            theFunctionIneedToAccess(P1, P2);
        }
    }
}
```

This at least does not throw an error, but I **ALWAYS GET `rootPage = null` for this**.

I tested unifying the namepsaces (i.e. `namespace theMain` for both), but this did not help.

What am I doing wrong here????

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you be more clear on , what you would like to achieve !? More clear requirement can help us understand it better. Why you want access mainpage from other page?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! I have a `mainList` in MainPage, where registered users are stored. **I want to update both the list and the UI** (MainPage.xaml) so users can know if they successfully registered/unregistered my service. I checked I can access to the MainPage using the official sample; I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your definition, `MainPage.Current` gets an instance of the currently loaded `MainPage`.

If your `MainPage.Current` is always null, please check whether the `MainPage` is already loaded in the **Frame**. When you try to get the `MainPage.Current` before the `MainPage` is loaded, the `Current` has not been assigned at this time, of course, it will be displayed as null.

In the `OnLaunched` method in App.xaml.cs, there is such a piece of code:

```cs
if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
{
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Please make sure you call the method of `MainPage.Current` after this code finishes executing.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A better design is to update the **state** of your application and then let the UI **react** to it, rather than trying to drive the UI directly. Any time you have a tight coupling with a different page in your application that's a sign something is *probably* wrong.

In this case, you could store a list of registered users somewhere in your application (maybe it's a static class, or a property of the `App` object, etc.) and then have the `MainPage` UI read from that list. Note that [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) won't work directly, since you will probably have to deal with access across different threads, but it is easy enough for the `MainPage` to have its own helper code that listens to change events, dispatches to the correct thread, and then notifies the app.